# Remove “Place order” button for specific shipping method, except on the Order-Pay endpoint

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, endpoint, shipping-method

I would like to remove the "Place order" button when a specific shipping method is selected, using the code of the excellent *LoicTheAztec* "[Disable “Place order” button for specific shipping method in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324907/disable-place-order-button-for-specific-shipping-method-in-woocommerce/57325311#57325311)" but excluding the order-pay endpoint.

I tried the following solution but it doesn't work, the Place Order button also disappears on the order-pay endpoint.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'disable_place_order_button_html' );
function disable_place_order_button_html( $button ) {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {  
        // HERE define your targeted shipping method id
        $targeted_shipping_method = "table_rate:3";
    
        // Get the chosen shipping method (if it exist)
        $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
        
        // If the targeted shipping method is selected, we disable the button
        if( in_array( $targeted_shipping_method, $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
            $style  = 'style="background:Silver !important; color:white !important; cursor: not-allowed !important; text-align:center;"';
            $text   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $button = '<a class="button" '.$style.'>' . $text . '</a>';
        }
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works for me. The problem is not related to this code.

The hook for the **Pay for order** button is [**`woocommerce_pay_order_button_html`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-checkout-form-pay.html#source-view.91) and not `woocommerce_order_button_html`. You find it in the template: `/woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php`

> You could remove the `! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )` check
> because it will never run on that page.

You could check a few things:

- Is the user who accesses this page logged in?
- Check your active theme's **functions.php** file if there are any other functions using the `woocommerce_pay_order_button_html` hook.
- Have you installed any plugins that manage / edit this page (besides WooCommerce)?
- Finally, check that there is no CSS rule hiding the element

Comment: It was a conceptual mistake, I didn't notice the different "place order" hook in the "Order-pay" endpoint. So I just replaced woocommerce_order_button_html with ywraq_quote_button_checkout_html (a hook of "Yith Woocommerce Request a Quote" plugin for the quote request button on checkout), which I need to appear and disappear depending on the shipping method.

Thanks so much

Comment: The strange thing was that the woocommerce_order_button_html hook removed the "place order" also in the order-pay endpoint, probably due to a theme or jquery incompatibility (I tried with a default theme and it works)