# Hide Place Order button for specific payment methods in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

How to disable the "place an order" button ONLY for the "Cheque" gateway. I don't want my users to place an order for this gateway because they need to make a contact through the given info before making any payments.

I found [Remove Woocommerce "place order" button for a specific shipping class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354331/remove-woocommerce-place-order-button-for-a-specific-shipping-class/50356340#50356340) which is what I want to do, but for "cheque" payment method instead.

I tried to replace the ID 332 with the "Cheque" ID but it completely removed the button for all gateways. its ID on the backend is `cheque` and the ID and class on the checkout page `payment_method_cheque`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_order_button_html' );
function remove_order_button_html( $button ) {
    // HERE define your targeted shipping class
    $targeted_payment_method = 'payment_method_cheque';
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $targeted_shipping_class ) {
            $found = true; // The targeted shipping class is found
            break; // We stop the loop
        }
    }

    // If found we remove the button
    if( $found )
        $button = '';

    return $button;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** It's a bit less complicated than you thought, but needs some jQuery to refresh checkout… Try the following instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_html', 'remove_place_order_button_for_specific_payments' );
function remove_place_order_button_for_specific_payments( $button ) {
    // HERE define your targeted payment(s) method(s) in the array
    $targeted_payments_methods = array('cheque');
    $chosen_payment_method     = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); // The chosen payment

    // For matched payment(s) method(s), we remove place order button (on checkout page)
    if( in_array( $chosen_payment_method, $targeted_payments_methods ) && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $button = ''; 
    }
    return $button;
}

// jQuery - Update checkout on payment method change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Change Pay button on checkout based on Woocommerce chosen payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405604/change-pay-button-on-checkout-based-on-woocommerce-chosen-payment-method/49408348#49408348)

Comment: I tried it on Woocommerce v3.9.1 first but it didn't do anything. then tried it on the latest version and it removed the button for all gateways. I also tested other IDs like `paypal` or `cod` but it didn't work at all ! It's weird ! I mean why would it at least run the code for `cheque` and wouldn't do the same for other IDs ? what's the difference ? either way, the code doesn't work properly.